# while unit testing ui-router config, ui-router's resolve function returns promise during expectation even after the service promise was resolved

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, jasmine, angular-mock

Below is the sample route configuration that I have for myApp using ui-router

```
    angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

    angular.module('myApp').config(stateConfig);

    stateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider'];

    function stateConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {  
        $stateProvider.state('view1', {
            url: '/view1/:id?',
            templateUrl: 'app/view1/view1.html',
            resolve:{
                init: ['$stateParams', 'view1Service', function($stateParams, view1Service){
                    if($stateParams.id !== ''){
                        return view1Service.getIdData($stateParams.id)
                            .then(function(response){
                                return { data: response.data, responseStatus: response.status };                            
                            }, function(response){
                                return { data:{}, responseStatus: response.status }; 
                            });
                    }
                    else{
                        return { data:{}, responseStatus: 200 };
                    }
                }]
            },
            controller: 'View1Controller as controllerOne'
        })
        //some other routes with similar configuration

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/view1/');
    }
```

Here is the spec for the above code that I have for now. Since resolve function for view1 state is dependent on view1Service I have mocked view1Service and also made it to return a promise(if promise was not returned from mocked service then infinite digest() loop was occuring).

```
    describe('ui router config', function() {

        var $rootScope, $state, $injector, myServiceMock, state = 'view2', deferred, mockedService;

        beforeEach(function() {
            angular.mock.module('myApp');
            angular.mock.module('ui.router');

            angular.mock.module(function($provide){
                $provide.factory('view1Service', function($q){
                    function getIdData(id){
                        deferred = $q.defer();
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
                    return {getIdData: getIdData}
                });
            });

            inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$state_, _$injector_, $templateCache, _$stateParams_, view1Service) {
                    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
                    $state = _$state_;
                    $injector = _$injector_;
                    $stateParams = _$stateParams_;
                    $templateCache.put('app/view1/view1.html', '')
            })
        });

        it('should respond to URL', function() {
            expect($state.href(state, { id: 1 })).toEqual('#/view1/1');
        });

        it('should resolve data', function() {
            $state.go(state, {id: '9999'});
            deferred.resolve({
                data: 'some data',
                status: 666
            });
            $rootScope.$digest();
            expect($state).toBe('checking');
            expect($state.current.name).toBe(state+'q');

            // Call invoke to inject dependencies and run function
            expect($injector.invoke($state.current.resolve.init)).toBe('findAll+1');//this assertion fails with below error

        });

    });
```

I'm currently able to assert on the current state. I would like to test the resolve function's success and failure callback as well.

However I keep getting following error:

```
    Expected Promise({ $$state: Object({ status: 0 }) }) to be 'findAll+1'.
```

Any idea why resolve block keeps returning Promise object as above. First of all it shouldn't be returning a promise since view1Service was resolved. And to my understanding even if resolve block invocation returns a promise doesn't *expect* statement wait till its resolved? I tried even using .then on invocation call, that didn't work either.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You are transitioning to the state, which calls the resolve functions, and then you "resolve()" your deferred. All good here. But then you invoke the init function later, which returns a promise, which is an good. But you want to resolve the deferred after this, now that it's been setup.

Basically, I think you are calling "init" twice, once when you call "$state.go", and again explicitly afterwards.

You should be able to first do a $state.get('view1').resolve.init, to grab the init function that you want to test directly. Otherwise, calling "$state.go" will run it automatically.

Hope that helps!